# How to apply spell checking for Editable ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

`WPF` comes with an inbuilt feature of SpellCheck. SpellCheck is added to `TextBoxBase` object, which inherits all the `textual input controls` automatically. Thus any input control will automatically derive the Spell Checking functionality.

But I'm looking for a solution to set the spell checker for `editable ComboBox` which is not inherited from the `TextBoxBase`.Are there any way to set the spell check for Editable ComboBox controller ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to [declare your own `ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `ComboBox`. In that `ControlTemplate`, you can start with the default `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox`, which you can find on the [ComboBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

In the default template, you should see a `TextBox` named `PART_EditableTextBox`... as you might have guessed, this is the editable part of the `ComboBox`. Then all you need to do is to set the `SpellCheck.IsEnabled` Attached Property to `True` on it and apply your new `ControlTemplate` as your `ComboBox.Template` value:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
               SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
               Style="{x:Null}"
               Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="3,3,23,3"
               Focusable="True"
               Background="Transparent"
               Visibility="Hidden"
               IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
```